# How to assign array in smarty in WHMCS

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, whmcs

In my WHMCS I'm trying to create array in one of the .tpl files.

```
{php}
  $uk_tlds = array(".co.uk",".me.uk",".org.uk",".uk",".london");
  $this->assign('uk_tlds',$uk_tlds);
{/php}

{foreach from=$uk_tlds key=num item=listtld}
    <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="{$listtld}"{if in_array($listtld,$tlds) || !$tlds && $num==1} checked{/if}>{$listtld}
{/foreach}
```

I would rather avoid using {php} if possible.

EDIT:
I found out that {php} has been deprecated from new version Smarty

Is there any way to make this work again?

Comment: What have you done to investigate the lack of php-support in the current version of Smarty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy, and you don't need {php} at all (in fact, you shouldn't ever use php in a smarty template file):

```
{$uk_tlds=[".co.uk",".me.uk",".org.uk",".uk",".london"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done more research and found how to solve my problem. 
This worked for me and might work for other people looking for quick solution after upgrading to new version but best is to avoid {php} thats why Borgtex sollution will work best.

Solution:
[WHMCS Version 6 Template MigrationGuide](http://docs.whmcs.com/Version_6_Template_Migration_Guide)

1) Enable {php} in WHMCS security settings

2) `$this->` become `$template->` in new version